# React unit testing const arrow function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following code:

```
render(){


        const nullValue = (
            <span>
                -
            </span>
        )

        const value = (propValue) => {     //untested line
            if (propValue === null) {      //untested line
                return nullValue           //untested line
            } else {
                return (                   //untested line
                    <span>
                         {propValue}
                    </span>
                )
            }
        }

        const percentageValue = (percentagePropValue) => {    //untested line
            if (percentagePropValue === null) {               //untested line
                return nullValue                              //untested line
            } else {
                return (                                      //untested line
                    <span>
                        {percentagePropValue * 100}%
                    </span>
                )
            }
        }

       return (                                             //untested line
           <div>
              <h1>Object Name: {value(this.state.myObject.name)}</h1>
              <h2>Object Percentage: {percentageValue(this.state.myObject.percentage)}</h2>
           </div>
       )
    }
```

The idea above is that the `value` and `percentageValue` functions use an object property as a parameter and then return a value to the user. If the value of property happens to be `null`, the value is replaced with a dash.

When running test coverage on the component, it says that `value` and `percentageValue` functions are not tested. I am assuming it is because of the if/else condition. What should I do in this situation? I don't really know how to deal with it.

Comment: *When running test coverage on the component* - if there are tests, please, list them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution using `enzyme`:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myObject: {
        name: null,
        percentage: null,
      },
    };
  }
  render() {
    const nullValue = <span>-</span>;

    const value = (propValue) => {
      if (propValue === null) {
        return nullValue;
      } else {
        return <span>{propValue}</span>;
      }
    };

    const percentageValue = (percentagePropValue) => {
      if (percentagePropValue === null) {
        return nullValue;
      } else {
        return <span>{percentagePropValue * 100}%</span>;
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Object Name: {value(this.state.myObject.name)}</h1>
        <h2>Object Percentage: {percentageValue(this.state.myObject.percentage)}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```js
import MyComponent from '.';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('61622176', () => {
  it('should render null object name and null object percentage', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
    expect(
      wrapper.find('h1').contains([
        <h1>
          Object Name: <span>-</span>
        </h1>,
        <h2>
          Object Percentage: <span>-</span>
        </h2>,
      ]),
    );
  });

  it('should render object name and object percentage', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
    wrapper.setState({ myObject: { name: 'ok', percentage: 0.5 } });
    expect(
      wrapper.find('h1').contains([
        <h1>
          Object Name: <span>ok</span>
        </h1>,
        <h2>
          Object Percentage: <span>50%</span>
        </h2>,
      ]),
    );
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61622176/index.test.jsx (8.017s)
  61622176
    ✓ should render null object name and null object percentage (9ms)
    ✓ should render object name and object percentage (1ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.039s
```